# How can i load the cascadeClassifier in Android OpenCv

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to port an existing opencv project to Android. But in current implementation in c++ i load the `cascadeClassifier` once when the program starts. But in android if i call my native functions from `onCameraFrame()` then i have to load the `cascadeClassifier` files every time i pass a frame to native code, which is a lot of work for the device.

Is there a way to load the `cascadeClassifier` once and then use it. I mean like loading it in java and passing it to jni call or any other alternative. ( I tried passing the loaded `cascadeClassifier` from java to jni call, But i am new to ndk. So i was unable to do so). I want to do this because loading 4 `cascadeClassifier` every frame makes the app chopy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to cache the instance on Java side in a Singleton and refer it back from JNI layer using JNI methods, e.g. You have a Java class `CascadeClassifierCacher` like below

```java
package com.arophix.jniexample.jniobjects;

public class CascadeClassifierCacher {

    private static CascadeClassifier cascadeClassifierCache = null;

    public static CascadeClassifier getCacheInstance() {
        if(cascadeClassifierCache == null) {
            cascadeClassifierCache = new CascadeClassifier();
        }

        return cascadeClassifierCache;
    }
}
```

From JNI side you can refer it using below flow: (knowing that your fully qualified package name is `com.arophix.jniexample.jniobjects.CascadeClassifierCacher`)

```
// Find the CascadeClassifierCacher class
jclass clazzId = env->FindClass("com/arophix/jniexample/jniobjects/CascadeClassifierCacher");
// Get the methodID
jmethodID jmethodIdGetCache = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "getCacheInstance", "()Lcom/arophix/jniexample/jniobjects/CascadeClassifierCacher;");
// Call getCacheInstance method.
jobject cacheInstance = (jobject) env->CallStaticObjectMethod(clazzId, jmethodIdGetCache);
```

Then you can use `cacheInstance` inside your JNI side.

Answer (score 0):

In your cpp file:

1. Create a separate Init() function to initialize the CascasdeClassifier once only.
2. Put detection call in a separate Detect() function and call this function from `onCameraFrame()`
   So the file won't be loaded for every frame.

```
CascadeClassifier faceCascade;

faceInit(...) {
    const char* absPath = "myfilepath\myfile.xml";
    std::string filePath(absPath);
    faceCascade.load(filePath);
}
    
faceDetect(...){
    ...
    faceCascade.detectMultiScale()
}
```